# Lync error in Silverlight: Client not trusted

Tags: c#, silverlight, lync-2010

When I try to load my Lync Controls in a Silverlight application I get the error: Client is not trusted. This error doesn't appear when I debug the Silverlight application without the corresponding web project.

This is the code that generates the error:

```
LyncClient l = LyncClient.GetClient();
```

This is the error:

```
AutomationServerException was unhandled by user code
Client is not trusted
```

What must I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error usually happens because the web site that your Silverlight application is running under isn't in the "Trusted Sites" browser zone. Adding to Trusted Sites should fix it.

**Edit:** The walkthrough [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg436952.aspx) states:

> Security settings for Microsoft Lync
>   2010 SDK applications require that the
>   host URL for Lync Control Silverlight
>   applications be added to the Trusted
>   sites list in Microsoft Internet
>   Explorer. For information about adding
>   to the Trusted sites list, see [Working with Internet Explorer 6 Security Settings](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/ie/ie6/using/howto/security/settings.mspx).

Comment: I am trying to use the Lync control in a standard ASP.NET application running on our intranet. The control works find when added to the trusted site list. The issue I have is that I need the site to be part of the local intranet list and IE prevents me from adding to the trusted site list as well.
Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: I don't thin there's any way around this. Unfortunately, the site MUST be in the trusted sites list for it to work. Fortunately this changes with Lync 2013, but not sure if this will help you with your predicament

Answer (score -2):

The probabble cause may be because of the security.Right click the dll and goto properties and set unblock.

Comment: Which dll? All the Lync dll's in Visual Studio?