# Deploy a Silverlight Lync application on IIS7

Tags: silverlight-4.0, iis-7, lync-2010, lync

I'm writing a Silverlight application in Visual Studio 2010 leaning on the walktroughs in the Lync SDK.

If I run the application in VS 2010 it all works in debug and in the release version.

If I try to deploy this to IIS7 the Silverlight is also running but I can't see the presence. The little square is without a filling color.

I assume some configuration is missing on IIS7?

My environment is a Windows Vista PC with local IIS7.

Can someone help me?

Comment: "ilverlight is also running but I can't see the presence. The little square is without a filling color." - can you upload a screenshot, it's hard to tell what this means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you add the site to your browsers Trusted Sites zone? see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734514/lync-error-in-silverlight-client-not-trusted/4734800#4734800)

Comment: Hey, I try it and drop a message at monday. Thank you

Comment: Hi Paul, sorry for the long delay. I have to clarify something. The trusted Zone is a domain Policy and i can't change it. Do you know a way? So i have to wait for a developer envoirment without policies. I think also, silverlight can't reach the Lync-CLient and ask him for the states of requested contact. I'll try it and will drop an update. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Other than getting friendly with (or bribing) your IT guys, no. If you're going to do any long-term lync development (particularly server side or mid tier i.e. bots), then I'd strongly recommend setting up your own virtual dev environment - its actually pretty straightforward. The post here (http://blogs.technet.com/b/mbaher/archive/2010/09/15/lync-server-2010-lab-deployment-guide-part-1.aspx) looks good, to keep things simpler you could consolidate the DC and the CA, and lose the edge server and the edge firewall - that works well for me

Comment: So you would build one Win 2008 R2 server as a Domain Controller and Certificate Authority, and one Win 2008 R2 server as your Lync Standard Edition server - then one Win7 box for the client - a day or twos work, but will save you masses of headache in the long run

Comment: Long lont time ago. Thats the right answer. The site must add to the trusted site. After that, it works immediately. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Lync SDK
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2464845

Comment: +1 because also a helpful right answer. But Paul answers first and his answer is also correct. Thank you too.

Comment: the combination of both this fix and the trusted sites answer resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of adding the site to the Trusted Sites zone in addition to installing the fix below seems to resolve this issue.

[Cumulative update package for Lync 2010: January 2011](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2467763)