# Web App works fine on Visual Studio 2010 but not IIS?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, iis, lync-2010

I am having a problem with deploying a web application I have developed.  It is a Lync SilverLight Applicaton (ASP.NET MVC Web Project).  When I run this from Visual Studio everything works fine.  Its runs it here http://localhost:53258/Default.aspx

Now with IIS I created under Default Web Site I created a New Application (SeatPlan - this is a seat plan web for my office with Lync integration).  I copied all the files from my Visual Studio solution to C:\Websites\SeatPlan - and within IIS on my new application I point to the folder.  If I then browse from content view from default.aspx I get the following URL - http://localhost/SeatPlan/Default.aspx - again on my own machine everything is working fine.

However if I copy this folder (C:\Websites\SeatPlan) to a collagues machine and he adds to IIS and broweses to the site the full functionality is not there - when he clicks a person on the seat plan the Lync Silverlight adds the name to the search box but doesnt bring back the person in the results list.  However in mine when i click on a person it brings back there details and I can then hover over this to start an instant conversation, etc.

Anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this or any possible steps to try to try and fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the site to the browsers Trusted Sites zone on your colleagues machine? see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734514/lync-error-in-silverlight-client-not-trusted/4734800#4734800)